# Aggregate SQLite function - unexpected result

Tags: sqlite

This `sqlite` query returns zero rows as expected:

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE 0;
```

This query, on the other hand, returns one row containing a null column:

```
SELECT MAX(1) FROM tbl WHERE 0;
```

Why does the second query return one row, rather than zero rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Normal' queries return one result for each (filtered) record of the table in the FROM clause.

However, when you are using some aggregate function, the result has one record for each *group* in the source table. And if there is no GROUP BY clause, the entire table is one group.

With GROUP BY, there are no results for empty groups.
However, without GROUP BY, you always have exactly one group and get one result record, even if that group ends up being empty.

Your query would get zero rows with MAX if it were also using GROUP BY (with a constant value, which would put all records, if there were any, into a single group):

```
SELECT MAX(1) FROM tbl WHERE 0 GROUP BY NULL;
```